Session Persistence Issue Between Two Django Projects Using Both JWT and Session Authentication
Background
Project A
Legacy system
Django full-stack server based on a template language
Using sessions for authentication
Python version 3.8
Django version 3.2
Project B
New project
JSON-based Django RESTful API server
Using both JWT and sessions for authentication
Python version 3.11
Django version 5.0
Database: MariaDB
Currently, we are migrating from the legacy Project A to Project B. During this process, we have switched the authentication method to JWT, but since the entire legacy system has not been migrated yet, we are maintaining the session method alongside it. Both projects use UserenaAuthenticationBackend and utilize django.contrib.auth.authenticate and django.contrib.auth.login for login.
In this state, users might log in using either Project A or Project B, which shares the same database. The following issues arise:
AS-IS

Logging into A from one browser -> Logging into B from another browser -> User gets logged out from A in the first browser.

Logging into B from one browser -> Logging into A from another browser -> User gets logged out from B in the first browser.

Logging into A from one browser -> Logging into A from another browser -> User remains logged into A in the first browser.

Logging into B from one browser -> Logging into B from another browser -> User remains logged into B in the first browser.


TO-BE
The goal is for a user to stay logged in across multiple sessions, regardless of whether they log in from different projects or browsers.
Suspicious part
The SESSION_COOKIE_NAME is unified with the same name value.
I suspected that this issue might be due to version differences, but aside from the change in the session.encode format in Django 4.0, which was related to the default algorithm changing to SHA1, there haven't been significant changes. Both Project A and Project B are using SHA256, so this doesn't seem to be the cause.
The sessions in the database are not expired. Sessions are created for each browser, but when logging in again, the session for the respective browser is overwritten rather than expiring other sessions (the expiration dates remain unchanged).

Try altering SESSION_COOKIE_NAME in one of the projects, so that each project has a unique cookie identifier for the user's session.

Please [edit] and provide us a [mre] that we can run to reproduce your problem. My best guess would be that you have a custom get_session_auth_hash method for both of your projects and when logging in you're changing the database state (assuming shared database) in such a way that the generated hash becomes invalid for the other project. Also please [edit] the question title and don't capitalize each word! Write it like a normal sentence.
